# Determining date of change in data using MS Access

Tags: ms-access, gaps-and-islands

I am working with data where new records are created every time a value is changed on a customer record. Due to system constraints, I have to use MS Access.

I am attempting to determine the current “Country” by unique email address along with the date that the most recent country value was first ‘chosen’.

Here’s an example table with an expected answer:

[image]

I’ve been playing with ‘Island/Gap’ strategies to manipulate the data.  However, nothing seems to lead me toward my ultimate goal.

Comment: Could you explain what about the Island/Gap approach you have attempted, and why you aren't sure it's leading you to your goal? Also, are you looking for a SQL solution, VBA, or does it matter?

Comment: If you have been able to retrieve the data in a format like described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780(v=sql.80).aspx  then you could either sort your output in descending order on the 'end' value (your date) and take the 'Start' value (first date associated with that final row); or you may be able to just take 'Top 1' after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this query do:

```
Select Top 1 Email, Country, EffectiveDate
From EmailCountry
Where Country = 
    (Select Country 
    From EmailCountry 
    Where EffectiveDate = 
        (Select Max(EffectiveDate) 
        From EmailCountry))
Order By EffectiveDate Asc
```